# Issue with raw loader while using ng-include in webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, gulp, webpack-2

I have a scenario where i need to load template using ng-include in my angular app.

```
<div ng-include src="'app/dummy/dummy.html'"></div>
```

This above html template is not loading and my application configured through webpack where i have used raw loader for loading the html templates.

```
test: /\.html$/,
loader: "raw-loader"
```

but it is not working as required with ng-include and the ng-include statement is getting commented in the browser.

please look into the folder structure below and my 'ng-include' is in index.html

[please click here for folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXJHC.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `<div ng-include="'app/dummy/dummy.html'"></div>` or `<ng-include src="'app/dummy/dummy.html'"/>`

Comment: No this syntax is correct as well.

Comment: Can you tell me @Pannala where is your dummy.html (i mean complete path) and the html where you are including it (full path).

Comment: please look into the updated question -@vertika